# Download latest GitHub release

Tags: github, tags, release

I want to add the **Download Latest Version** button to my project website which would represent the link to the latest release stored at **GitHub Releases**.

I've tried to create a release tag named `latest`, but it became complicated when I tried to load a new release (confusion with tag creation date, tag interchanging, etc.). Updating download links on my website manually is also a time-consuming and tedious task.

Note that my website is hosted statically, so I simply **can't use server-side scripting** to generate links. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Github now provides a "Latest release" button on the release page of a project, **after you have created your first release**.

In the example you gave, this button links to https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/latest

Comment: This method appears to be dead on the projects I was interested in using it with. :(

Comment: @ThorSummoner: some project maintainers don't bother to add releases. In [such cases](https://github.com/webix-hub/tracker/issues/247), the API will return an empty array.

Answer (score 25):

You don't need any scripting to generate a download link for the latest release. Simply use this format:

```
https://github.com/:owner/:repo/zipball/:branch
```

Examples:

```
https://github.com/webix-hub/tracker/zipball/master
https://github.com/iDoRecall/selection-menu/zipball/gh-pages
```

---

If for some reason you want to obtain a link to the latest release download, including its version number, you can obtain that from the [get latest release API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest
```

Example:

```js
$.get('https://api.github.com/repos/idorecall/selection-menu/releases/latest', function (data) {
  $('#result').attr('href', data.zipball_url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="result">Download latest release (.ZIP)</a>
```

Comment: If you need a .tar.gz file instead, then you can replace `zipball` in the url with `tarball`.

Comment: https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/releases/latest returns 404. This returns empty string: https://api.github.com/repos/webix-hub/tracker/releases while both of these projects have releases. Why is the API behavior inconsistent? Any documentation on this?

Comment: @HamidSarfraz: From GitHub support, `jquery` and `webix-hub` don't have releases, they have tags, and the [latest release API doesn't work with tags](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository). A full release looks like [this](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.17.2) and if you want to list git tags, you can use https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Thanks. That was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Since [February  18th, 2015](https://developer.github.com/changes/2015-02-18-new-releases-api-methods/), the [GitHUb V3 release API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) has a [get latest release API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release).

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest
```

See also "[Linking to releases](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/linking-to-releases)".

---

Still, the name of the asset can be tricky.

[Git-for-Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), for instance, requires a command like:

```sh
curl -IkLs -o NUL -w %{url_effective} \
   https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest|\
grep -o "[^/]*$"| sed "s/v//g"|\
xargs -I T echo \
  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/vT/PortableGit-T-64-bit.7z.exe \
  -o PortableGit-T-64-bit.7z.exe| \
sed "s/.windows.1-64/-64/g"|sed "s/.windows.\(.\)-64/.\1-64/g"|\
xargs curl -kL
```

The first 3 lines extract the latest version `2.35.1.windows.2`
The rest will build the right URL

```
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/
        v2.35.1.windows.2/PortableGit-2.35.1.2-64-bit.7z.exe
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to download from Linux — even old or tiny versions — or are trying to download from a BASH script then the failproof way is using this command:

```
wget https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/releases/latest -O - | awk -F \" -v RS="," '/browser_download_url/ {print $(NF-1)}' | xargs wget
```

Do not forget to replace `$OWNER` and `$REPO` with the right owner and repository names. The command downloads a JSON page with the data of the latest release. Then `awk` gets the value from the `browser_download_url` key.

If you are on a really old version of Linux or a tiny embedded system with a small `wget`, the download name can be a problem. In such a case you can always use the ultra-reliable:

```
URL=$(wget https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/releases/latest -O - | awk -F \" -v RS="," '/browser_download_url/ {print $(NF-1)}'); wget $URL -O $(basename "$URL")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following where:

- **${Organization}** as the GitHub user or organization
- **${Repository}** is the repository name

`curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/${Organization}/${Repository}/tarball > ${Repository}.tar.gz`

The top level directory in the .tar.gz file has the sha hash of the commit in the directory name which can be a problem if you need an automated way to change into the resulting directory and do something.

The method below will strip this out, and leave the files in a folder with a predictable name.

`mkdir ${Repository}
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/${Organization}/${Repository}/tarball | tar -zxv -C ${Repository} --strip-components=1`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe could you use some client-side scripting and dynamically generate the target of the link by invoking the GitHub api, through some JQuery magic?

The Releases API exposes a way to **[retrieve the list of all the releases from a repository](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository)**. For instance, **[this link](https://api.github.com/repos/reactiveui/reactiveui/releases)** return a Json formatted list of all the **[releases of the ReactiveUI project](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases)**.

Extracting the first one would return the latest release.

Within this payload:

- The `html_url` attribute will hold the first part of the url to build (ie. `https://github.com/{owner}/{repository}/releases/{version}`).
- The `assets` array will list of the downloadable archives. Each `asset` will bear a `name` attribute

Building the target download url is only a few string operations away.

- Insert the `download/` keyword between the `releases/` segment from the html_url and the version number
- Append the name of the asset to download

Resulting url will be of the following format: `https://github.com/{owner}/{repository}/releases/download/{version}/name_of_asset`

For instance, regarding the Json payload from the link ReactiveUI link above, we've got `html_url: "https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/5.99.0"` and one asset with `name: "ReactiveUI.6.0.Preview.1.zip"`.

As such, the download url is https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/download/5.99.0/ReactiveUI.6.0.Preview.1.zip

Comment: Thanks, your method is good, but I don't want to tie user to JS, because it simply can be turned off on the user side (and using `<noscript>` tag harks us back to the issue of bulkiness).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ambrosechua/d426ac039e0a5f09059c is a quick draft script to do this, but only works on releases but not source code downloads.

Answer (score 1):

If you using PHP try follow code:

```
function getLatestTagUrl($repository, $default = 'master') {
    $file = @json_decode(@file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/$repository/tags", false,
        stream_context_create(['http' => ['header' => "User-Agent: Vestibulum\r\n"]])
    ));

    return sprintf("https://github.com/$repository/archive/%s.zip", $file ? reset($file)->name : $default);
}
```

Function usage example

```
echo '<a href="' .getLatestTagUrl('OzzyCzech/vestibulum') .'">Download</a>';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, _GitHub Pages_ service does not support PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't see the answer here, but it was quite helpful for me while running continuous integration tests, this one-liner that only requires you to have curl will allow to search the Github repo's releases to download the latest version

https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/a4cd19cda655b8249d908261a62687f8

I use it to run PHPSTan on our repository using the following script

https://gist.github.com/rvanlaak/7491f2c4f0c456a93f90e31774300b62

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Dan Dascalescu in a comment to accepted answer, there are some projects (roughly 30%) which do not bother to file formal releases, so neither "Latest release" button nor /releases/latest API call would return useful data.

To *reliably* fetch the latest release for a GitHub project, you can use [lastversion](https://github.com/dvershinin/lastversion).