# Is there a link to GitHub for downloading a file in the latest release of a repository?

Tags: github, download, release, github-pages

Using [GitHub's Release feature](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software), it is possible to provide a link to download a specific version of the published software. However, every time a release is made, the gh-page also needs to be updated.

Is there a way to get a link to a specific file of whatever the latest version of a software is?

e.g., this would be a static link:

`https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/releases/download/v0.0.0/package.zip`

What I'd like is something like:

`https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/releases/download/latest/package.zip`

> NOTE: The difference between this question and
>   [GitHub latest release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439239/github-latest-release) is
>   that this question specifically asks for getting access to the file,
>   not the GitHub latest release page

Comment: This is supported natively by Github now (with a slight difference in the URL format). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987542/is-there-a-link-to-github-for-downloading-a-file-in-the-latest-release-of-a-repo/54836319#54836319

Comment: It is interesting how the question is clearly about a LINK, but so many answers are about retrieving an asset :))

Answer (score 181, accepted):

A few years late, but I just implemented a simple redirect to support `https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/releases/latest/download/package.zip`. That should redirected to the latest tagged `package.zip` release asset. Hope it's handy!

Comment: Documented on https://help.github.com/en/articles/linking-to-releases: _If you'd like to link directly to a download of your latest release asset you can link to /owner/name/releases/latest/download/asset-name.zip_

Comment: It would be helpful if this feature worked with versioned asset names, however.

Comment: Note that the order is switched `.../releases/latest/download/...` vs `.../releases/download/v0.0.0/...`. You cannot simply replace `v0.0.0` with `latest` in place.

Comment: @Joshua Peek Maybe you could extend this to expand "LATEST" in the asset name to be the version string? That would make it useful for assets with version numbers in their name.

Comment: What about downloading the latest source code? What is the name of the asset in that case?

Comment: Currently **/releases/latest/download/package.zip** is no longer work. Result in not found. Example: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases/latest/download/package.zip

Comment: this does still work

Comment: Doesn't work for me as well: https://github.com/rust-lang/mdBook/releases/latest/download/package.zip.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. Where did you implement this? Do you work at Github and just like that implemented the feature. Or is it an API available at an URL that's somehow not linked to?

Comment: The people in the comments who are saying this isn't working are likely confused by the fact this answer is only giving an example of downloading a file called "package.zip" from the release. If your asset is called "foo.zip", you need to change it to that. If your asset is called "foo-1.2.3.zip" where 1.2.3 is the version of the release, you'll have to use a different method.

Comment: @gsgx what he is mentioning is a very common issue about that, sadly it looks like GitHub has no solution to that just yet

Comment: As github cannot know which file you want when you say 'latest' it's impossible to avoid having the file name in the link. For example : https://github.com/rust-lang/mdBook/releases/latest/download/mdbook-v0.4.28-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip .
But then this doesn't really help because when you call latest you don't know the version and maybe don't care so it's like a half working system.

Comment: @gsgx Whilst these users both linked to package.zip files that didn't exist (causing the download to fail), I think that they are (accidentally) correct that this method no longer works. At least, it doesn't appear to work for me.

Answer (score 72):

Linux solution to get latest release asset download link (works only if release has one asset only)

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/boxbilling/boxbilling/releases/latest | grep browser_download_url | cut -d '"' -f 4
```

Comment: One additional grep in the pipeline will find the file for your distribution and architecture. For the [atom](https://github.com/atom/atom) text editor on 64-bit Ubuntu: `curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/atom/atom/releases | grep browser_download_url | grep '64[.]deb' | head -n 1 | cut -d '"' -f 4`

Comment: There is no browser_download_url any more. You can use tarball_url now. `curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/git-ftp/git-ftp/releases | grep tarball_url | head -n 1 | cut -d '"' -f 4`

Comment: @maikel grepping for browser_download_url still works for me.

Comment: @léo-lam You are right. Just if you don't have assets, you can use the tarball_url to get the source code.

Comment: You can only load the latest release to avoid  `| head -n 1`
https://api.github.com/repos/boxbilling/boxbilling/releases/latest

Comment: @ya.teck `/latest` only list stable release, not draft or prerelease: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release

Answer (score 35):

You can do an [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) request to get latest release download URL using the [GitHub Releases API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#get-the-latest-release). It also shows when it was released and the download count:

```js
function GetLatestReleaseInfo() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/ShareX/ShareX/releases/latest").done(function(release) {
        UpdateDownloadButton(release, ".exe", $(".setup"));
        UpdateDownloadButton(release, "portable.zip", $(".portable"));
    });
}

function UpdateDownloadButton(release, assetExtension, element) {
    let asset = release.assets.find(asset => asset.name.endsWith(assetExtension));
    let releaseInfo = "Version: " + release.tag_name.substring(1) +
        "\nFile size: " + (asset.size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + " MB" +
        "\nRelease date: " + new Date(asset.updated_at).toLocaleDateString("en-CA") +
        "\nDownload count: " + asset.download_count.toLocaleString();

    element.attr("href", asset.browser_download_url);
    element.attr("title", releaseInfo);
}

GetLatestReleaseInfo();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="setup" href="https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/latest">Setup</a>
<a class="portable" href="https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/latest">Portable</a>
```

When the request completes, the URL of buttons will change automatically to a direct download URL.

Comment: Cool. Do you know why this might not be working? `curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/DataTables/DataTables/releases/latest`

Comment: Because you don't have any release. Check: https://api.github.com/repos/DataTables/DataTables/releases

Comment: Funky... https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/releases shows a bunch of releases. There must be some ambiguity there.

Comment: No, these are only tags. There are no releases.

Comment: Why is this blank? https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/releases There should be plenty of releases.

Comment: https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/releases/latest returns 404. This returns empty string: https://api.github.com/repos/webix-hub/tracker/releases while both of these projects have releases. Why is the API behavior inconsistent? Any documentation on this?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases they don't have any releases. It is just version tags.

Comment: This is useless for the places where it would be needed. As in: Shell scripts.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine question was asking it for web pages not shell scripts.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to do this server-sided. Also, unless someone is already using jquery, prescribing it for this _one_ thing is overkill. Ajax with vanilla JS isn't hard. Unless you want extremely wide browser support. In that case, do it on the server side. Unless there's some reason to doing it client side, but if there is that should be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @CoryRs I'm using GitHub pages for static web site hosting therefore couldn't do it server side.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is automate getting the download url for the latest release available on github, then @IanB's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29360657/1365918) below is the way to go. Using jq to parse the output from Github's API and getting the download url needed. You can then use wget to get the actual file. Tried and tested in scripts and works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 19):

From the command line using `curl` and `jq`, retrieves the *first* file of the *latest* release:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/porjo/staticserve/releases/latest | \
  jq --raw-output '.assets[0] | .browser_download_url'
```

Comment: `jq --raw-output` is a cleaner way to drop the quotes.  If you only want the latest it's cheaper to fetch `.../releases/latest` and drop the `.[0] | `.  But fetching all releases allows queries like `jq '.[] | .assets[] | .browser_download_url | select(endswith(".deb"))'`...

Comment: Thanks Beni, I expanded on this for grabbing the latest docker-compose, ```curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest" | jq --arg PLATFORM_ARCH "$(echo `uname -s`-`uname -m`)" -r '.assets[] | select(.name | endswith($PLATFORM_ARCH)).browser_download_url' | xargs sudo curl -L -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose --url ```. The endswith was the magic and using the arch allows me to ignore the whatever.sha256 files that are typically present without doing `|head -n 1`.

Answer (score 11):

Another Linux solution using curl and wget to download a single binary file from the [latest release page](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/releases/latest)

```
curl -s -L https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/releases/latest | egrep -o '/bosun-monitor/bosun/releases/download/[0-9]*/scollector-linux-armv6' | wget --base=http://github.com/ -i - -O scollector
```

Explanation:

`curl -s -L` is to silently download the latest release HTML (after following redirect)

`egrep -o '...'` uses regex to find the file you want

`wget --base=http://github.com/ -i -` converts the relative path from the pipeline to absolute URL

and `-O scollector` sets the desired file name.

may be able to add `-N` to only download if the file is newer but S3 was giving a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: My goal is to make a link on a website that always points to the latest version. A linux command will not allow that.

Comment: This is what I was looking for but you have to make sure you have the correct escape characters for wildcards and dots when using grep.

Comment: @TdotThomas thanks, that's the hint I needed for semver release numbers to escape the periods `\.` e.g. 2.2.0 needed `/download/[0-9\.]*/`

Comment: No, it doesn't. No escape char. But i **would** presume an optional `v` as prefix, like a tag `v0.11.0`. Just input `curl -s -L https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/releases/latest | egrep -o '/bosun-monitor/bosun/releases/download/[v]?[0-9.]*/scollector-linux-armv6' | wget --base=http://github.com/ -i - -O scollector` in your CLI and it works perfectly. Thank you, Greg!!

Answer (score 9):

Github now supports static links for downloading individual files from the latest release: https://help.github.com/en/articles/linking-to-releases

```
https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/releases/latest/download/package.zip
```

Comment: The same answer was already posted 6 months prior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987542/is-there-a-link-to-github-for-downloading-a-file-in-the-latest-release-of-a-repo/54836319#54836319

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention @wisbucky, I dismissed it then since it sounded like a custom implementation from a developer, not someone from StackOverflow!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work even thought it's in the docs - also it would be inconsistent to see /releases/latest/download/ when download links are of the style /releases/download/0.7.1/... (the version is at the end)

Answer (score 9):

This can be done in a single one-liner like so:

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/slmingol/gorelease_ex/releases/latest \
    | grep -wo "https.*Linux.*gz" | wget -qi -
```

Here we're:

- Pulling the API side of GitHub to get information about the release artifacts with the tag `latest`.
- Parse that output looking for an artifact that matches the pattern `https.*Linux.*gz`.
- Pass the URL to the command `wget -qi -` so that it'll get downloaded

To further reveal what's going on here's a broader `grep` of the API endpoint:

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/slmingol/gorelease_ex/releases/latest | grep -wo "https.*" | grep gz
https://github.com/slmingol/gorelease_ex/releases/download/0.0.78/gorelease_ex_0.0.78_Darwin_x86_64.tar.gz"
https://github.com/slmingol/gorelease_ex/releases/download/0.0.78/gorelease_ex_0.0.78_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz"
```

Above you can see the URLs that matched.

### Further tip

You can also parameterize the `grep` argument so that it'll "dynamically" determine what platform it was run on and substitute in the appropriate string based on that.

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/slmingol/gorelease_ex/releases/latest \
    | grep -wo "https.*$(uname).*gz" | wget -qi -
```

Here `$(uname)` will return either Darwin, Linux, etc.

Comment: this is neat with `grep` regexp, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 8):

Just use one of the urls below to download the latest release:
(took urls from boxbilling project for example): https://api.github.com/repos/boxbilling/boxbilling/releases

Download the latest release as zip:
https://api.github.com/repos/boxbilling/boxbilling/zipball

Download the latest release as tarball:
https://api.github.com/repos/boxbilling/boxbilling/tarball

Click on one of the urls to download the latest release instantly. As i wrote this lines it's currently: **boxbilling-boxbilling-4.20-30-g452ad1c[.zip/.tar.gz]**

**UPDATE:** Found an other url in my logfiles (ref. to example above)
https://codeload.github.com/boxbilling/boxbilling/legacy.tar.gz/master

Comment: those are repos not releases

Answer (score 8):

As noted previously, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) is useful for this and other [REST APIs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/).

### tl;dr - more details below

Assuming you want the **macOS** release:

```sh
URL=$( curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/atom/atom/releases/latest" \
   | jq -r '.assets[] | select(.name=="atom-mac.zip") | .browser_download_url' )
curl -LO "$URL"
```

### Solution for atom releases

*Note* each repo can have different ways of providing the desired artifact, so I will demonstrate for a well-behaved one like [atom](https://github.com/atom/atom).

#### Get the names of the assets published

```sh
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/atom/atom/releases/latest" \
    | jq -r '.assets[] | .name'

atom-1.15.0-delta.nupkg
atom-1.15.0-full.nupkg
atom-amd64.deb
...
```

#### Get the download URL for the desired asset

Below **atom-mac** is my desired asset via jq's `select(.name=="atom-mac.zip")`

```sh
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/atom/atom/releases/latest" \
    | jq -r '.assets[] | select(.name=="atom-mac.zip") | .browser_download_url'

https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/download/v1.15.0/atom-mac.zip
```

#### Download the artifact

```sh
curl -LO "https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/download/v1.15.0/atom-mac.zip"
```

#### jq Playground

jq syntax can be difficult. Here's a playground for experimenting with the `jq` above:
https://jqplay.org/s/h6_LfoEHLZ

#### Security

You should take measures to ensure the validity of the downloaded artifact via [sha256sum and gpg](https://getfedora.org/verify), if at all possible.

Answer (score 8):

A solution using (an inner) wget to get the HTML content, filter it for the zip file (with egrep) and then download the zip file (with the outer wget).

```
wget https://github.com/$(wget https://github.com/<USER>/<PROJECT>/releases/latest -O - | egrep '/.*/.*/.*zip' -o)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Not possible according to GitHub support as of 2018-05-23**

Contacted support@github.com on 2018-05-23 with message:

> Can you just confirm that there is no way besides messing with API currently?

and they replied:

> Thanks for reaching out. We recommend using the API to fetch the latest release because that approach is stable, documented, and not subject to change any time soon:
>
> https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release

I will also keep tracking this at: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/658

**Python solution without any dependencies**

Robust and portable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import urllib.request

_json = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/releases/latest',
     headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'},
)).read())
asset = _json['assets'][0]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(asset['browser_download_url'], asset['name'])
```

See also:

- [What is the quickest way to HTTP GET in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python)
- [Basic http file downloading and saving to disk in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python)

**Also consider pre-releases**

`/latest` does not see pre-releases, but it is easy to do since `/releases` shows the latest one first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import urllib.request

_json = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/releases',
     headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'},
)).read())
asset = _json[0]['assets'][0]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(asset['browser_download_url'], asset['name'])
```

Comment: GitHub support didn't bother to check that their documentation is wrong? Plus don't they get it that end users need a consistent url and not scripts?

Answer (score 6):

The [Linking to releases](https://help.github.com/articles/linking-to-releases) help page does mention a "Latest Release" button, but that doesn't get you a download link.

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/latest

For that, you need to get the latest tag first (as mentioned in "[GitHub URL for latest release of the *download file*?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086563/6309)"):

```
latestTag=$(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)

curl -L https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/download/$latestTag/ReactiveUI-$latestTag.zip
```

Comment: This still requires to push a new version of the `gh-pages` branch everytime a new release is made; the objective is to have a static link I can use to just "refer to the latest version". Right now my best option is to just refer to the releases page.

Comment: @ChristianRondeau I agree. I didn't see anywhere in the API a way to reference the "latest" release archive full url directly.

Comment: Still, thanks for the tip; if no better answers are provided, I'll probably end up doing a script to update gh-pages using your script.

Answer (score 3):

I want to download the releases from the `README.md` file in the repository description. There, I cannot execute JavaScript.

I can add links like these to the README file or github pages for all of my repositories:

- `https://niccokunzmann.github.io/download_latest/<USER>/<REPOSITORY>/<FILE>`
  Downloads the latest release file from the repository.
- `https://niccokunzmann.github.io/download_latest/<FILE>`
  This works because the JavaScript referrer is set and the repository to download is determined through `document.referrer`. Thus, the link will also work for forks.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/download_latest), fork or just use my repo.

Comment: That's a pretty clever idea :) it won't work when sharing links or using curl or the likes, but this idea can be done in the project's github pages.

Comment: SInce this is possible as a JavaScript website, one could also write a service that does a redirect. http://download-service.com/organization/repository/artifact

Comment: Seems to work fine, any tips on how one can host it at their own xx.github.io site? (so that they're sure it stays alive and pointing to the files they expect it to)

Comment: You should be able to fork it and then enable github pages in the settings of the fork.

Answer (score 3):

in PHP - redirect to the latest release download. Simply put on your webspace

```
<?php

/**
 * Download latest release from github release articats
 * License: Public Domain
 */

define('REPO', 'imi-digital/iRobo');

$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => [
            'User-Agent: PHP'
        ]
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$releases = file_get_contents('https://api.github.com/repos/' . REPO . '/releases', false, $context);
$releases = json_decode($releases);

$url = $releases[0]->assets[0]->browser_download_url;

header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use just `curl` you can try with `-w '%{url_effective}'` that prints the URL after a redirect chain (followed by curl if you invoke it with `-L`). So, for example

```
curl -sLo /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}' https://github.com/github-tools/github/releases/latest
```

outputs `https://github.com/github-tools/github/releases/tag/v3.1.0`.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit of this solution is that you don't have to specify any release or tag number- it will just grab the **LATEST**.

### TESTING:

I conducted my testing using the following Github user & repo:

"***f1linux***" = Github User
"***pi-ap***" = Repo

The arbitrary directory name the repo is saved to is set in:

```
--one-top-level="pi-ap"
```

### DIRECT:

Using Firefox's "*Web Developer*" tools (3 bars in upper right corner), in the "*Network*" section I found `https://api.github.com` was redirecting to `https://codeload.github.com`, so by piping the `curl` to `tar` I was able to grab the latest versioned repo and save it to a predictable name so it could be operated on:

```
curl https://codeload.github.com/f1linux/pi-ap/legacy.tar.gz/master | tar xzvf - --one-top-level="pi-ap" --strip-components 1
```

### INDIRECT:

After I achieved fully-automated downloads of the latest versioned release using a *DIRECT* URL, I turned my attention to achieving the same with Github's redirection:

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/f1linux/pi-ap/tarball | tar xzvf - --one-top-level="pi-ap" --strip-components 1
```

### Preferred Method:

However, please note as per Von's comment below that **INDIRECT** is the [preferred method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60198721/10009950)

### Further Validation:

To ensure my results were reproducible to other versioned Github repos, the same tests were successfully executed for Digital Ocean's `doctl` api toolkit (which is what started the whole exercise actually!):

Both **DIRECT** and **INDIRECT** work using the same form as above, just changing the username & repo:

### DIRECT:

```
curl https://codeload.github.com/digitalocean/doctl/legacy.tar.gz/master | tar xzvf - --one-top-level="doctl" --strip-components 1
```

### INDIRECT:

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/repos/digitalocean/doctl/tarball | tar xzvf - --one-top-level="doctl" --strip-components 1
```

Comment: I ran into grief with the redirection initially and as noted in the answer Firefox's "Web Developer" tools got me going on the right track.  Couldn't stop there though, had to get it working with the redirection.  Thanks for the upvote- most obliged!

Comment: @VonC Just added your feedback to the answer.  I was totally unaware of this.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

This is for Linux.

I saw the above accepted answer

```
A few years late, but I just implemented a simple redirect to support https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/releases/latest/download/package.zip. That should redirected to the latest tagged package.zip release asset. Hope it's handy!
```

by [Joshua Peek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11104007/joshua-peek) but a comment noted it didn't support versioned file names.

After searching for a bit, I made up a one line call that works for versioned file names. It uses curl to get the latest file version and then makes use of the redirect support that was added to download the latest versioned file.

```
wget $'https://github.com/<UMBRELLA PROJECT>/<REPO NAME>/releases/latest/download/<FILE NAME START>-'$(curl -s https://github.com/<UMBRELLA PROJECT>/<REPO NAME>/releases/latest | grep -o -P '(?<=releases/tag/).*(?=\">)')$'<FILE NAME END>'
```

So it targets a file that's named like `<REPO NAME>-linux64_arm-<VERSION NUMBER>.tar.gz` that's on the webpage `https://github.com/<UMBRELLA PROJECT>/<REPO NAME>/releases/latest` after it redirects. It does this by looking for the `<VERSION NUMBER>` between `releases/tag/` and the `">` in the text that's returned from the curl call. So to be really explicit, `<FILE NAME START>` is the `<REPO NAME>-linux64_arm-` and `<FILE NAME END>` is the `.tar.gz` in the above example. Get the `START` and `END` bits by looking at what the `https://github.com/<UMBRELLA PROJECT>/<REPO NAME>/releases/latest` uses as its file naming scheme.

I made this up by mimicking how grep and curl were used by others and just learned all of this now, so let me know if it's doing something real naughty that I wouldn't even fathom! Also I am saying `<UMBRELLA PROJECT>` but a user name should be able to go there just fine as well. Shout out to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13245961/2403531 for the grep call, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10264 for the $string$concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use in **alpine**, follow these steps:

```
 apk add curl ca-certificates wget
```

```
wget -q $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/<USER>/<REPOSITORY>/releases/latest | grep browser_download_url | grep "$ARCH" | cut -d '"' -f 4)
```

The `-q` flag in wget is quiet mode. If you want to see the output then use without `-q`.

Answer (score 1):

In case that the repo is using just tags instead of release -- cf. jQuery -- the solutions which based on one URL does not work.

Instead, you have to query all tags, sort them and construct the download URL. I implemented such a solution for the language Go and the jQuery repo: [Link to Github](https://github.com/SommerEngineering/OceanCMS/blob/master/LoadLatestJQuery.go).

Perhaps, this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dirty trick that uses internal `github.com` webserver `latest` redirect rule. But this rule doesn't exist on `raw.githubusercontent.com` host.

For example we can install the latest available nvm using the following code:

```bash
curl -s -w '%header{location}' "https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases/latest/download/install.sh" | \
  sed -e 's/\/\/github.com/\/\/raw.githubusercontent.com/' -e 's/\/releases\/download//' | \
  xargs curl -o- | bash
```

Comment: Is the file install.sh unique to NVM's repo only or is this a widespread script that is commonly found on most if not all other repositories?

Comment: @slyfox1186 Hi, you can use it for every repo.

Comment: I tried ```curl -s -w '%header{location}' "https://github.com/yasm/yasm/releases/latest/download/install.sh" | \
  sed -e 's/\/\/github.com/\/\/raw.githubusercontent.com/' -e 's/\/releases\/download//' | \
  xargs curl -o- | bash``` and i didnt work. do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `yasm` release doesn't include install.sh script. See `https://github.com/yasm/yasm/releases` it has for example `yasm-1.3.0-win64.exe`. So you can do something like `curl -s -w '%header{location}' "https://github.com/yasm/yasm/releases/latest/download/yasm-1.3.0-win64.exe" | xargs curl -o- | start` where start is a command to run exe files in windows.

Answer (score 0):

simple command which works and download the latest package available in the github release

```
curl -ks https://api.github.com/repos/<reponame>/releases/latest | grep "browser_download_url.*linux-amd64.tar.gz" | cut -d : -f 2,3 | tr -d \" | xargs wget --no-check-certificate
```

- reponame - replace it with github repo with available packages in
  release
- Type of package .tar.gz can be replaced as per need. Ex -
  .zip etc

Answer (score 0):

There's also a way to download zipped code from a specific branch.:

```
https://github.com/<author>/<repo>/archive/refs/heads/main.zip
```

Example:

https://github.com/php-sage/sage/archive/refs/heads/main.zip

Docs:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/using-files/downloading-source-code-archives

Not release, just latest code in a branch, but I found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

To grab a listed tar.gz tarball use the following command.

I feel like this gets easier AS LONG as curl returns a string that matches the grep regex.... what I mean is some results DO NOT have a string that will match this but the ones who do this makes it pretty easy.

```
git_repo=yasm/yasm
curl -fsSL https://api.github.com/repos/${git_repo}/releases/latest | grep -Eo 'http.*\.tar\.gz' | head -n1
```