# update git with cli | programmer way of installation

Tags: git, shell, command-line, installation

Is it possible to update `git` with latest version available with command?

i.e. `git update` or `git update@2.7.2`

**Or** is there any other **programmer-way** of installation.

Comment: Is this on Linux only or on Windows?

Comment: I am using windows OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you can curl the latest Portable edition of [git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (listed in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest, a unique url which always reference the latest release).
See for example "[Is there a link to GitHub for downloading a file in the latest release of a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29360657/6309)"

- Unzip it in c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.x.y-64-bit (using the name of the portable edition you just downloaded).
- Make a symbolic link latest pointing to it

  ```
  rmdir latest
  mklink /J latest PortableGit-2.x.y-64-bit
  ```

(it actually is a junction, which does not require elevated privilege)

That way, you path can reference c:\prgs\git\latest\bin: each time you change that latest link, you update your git.
And since it is a portable edition, there is no setup involved.