# Github keep link in readme persistent to latest releases asset file

Tags: git, github

I have an installer file in the latest release and I want to have a persistent link in the readme to it. It seems that the `/releases/latest` isn't an alias that I could use to construct the path as `/releases/latest/mydownloader.exe`

The current workarounds I have:

1) Create a tag `release` and always delete and recreate it:

```
github.com/user/project/releases/download/release/install.exe
```

2) Modify `readme.md` anytime I do a new release and update path

```
github.com/user/project/releases/download/20190218/install.exe
```

Comment: I guess that's intended since a release can have many files in GitHub.
Why not pointing the release link in README to `/release/latest`? If you explain in the readme that the users have to download the .exe file, I'm sure that they will understand :)

Comment: No, we are listing different files, so we don't wan't them to open another page to then download.

Answer (score 2):

The tag remains the least intrusive option (you don't have to modify your README, adding a new commit on each release)

As explain in "[Is there a link to GitHub for downloading a file in the latest release of a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540591/6309)", there is no API support for referencing a latest released file as a permanent link.

Comment: thanks for your reply, at least I can rule out know that there is a workaround and yeah, I will keep updating the tag rather then creating a commit on the readme.

Answer (score 0):

you can point to `/releases/latest`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I needed something similar so here is the solution I found.

All we need is to reference the latest release using this path:

`github.com/user/project/releases/latest`

then we just need to append `/download/install.exe`, resulting in the following URL which should work:

`github.com/user/project/releases/latest/download/install.exe`

Note this is different from the path seen when downloading the file from the release page which requires the release name/tag as specified in the question.

I couldn't find documentation for this, but it seems to work.