# Is there a link to GitHub for downloading a file from the repo tagged with the latest release?

Tags: github, github-api

The question [Is there a link to GitHub for downloading a file in the latest release of a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987542/is-there-a-link-to-github-for-downloading-a-file-in-the-latest-release-of-a-repo) gives you all you need to know in order to get to any files that are part of the latest release in a GitHub repo.

Along the same line, I wonder if you can link to a file IN THE REPOSITORY (not in the release) that was tagged with that latest release?

So instead of

```
https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/blob/COMMIT_HASH/myfile.json
```

I would like something along the lines of

```
https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/blob/releases/lates/myfile.json
```

The option is of course to do it in two steps, using the [releases api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases) and then get to it, but I wonder if there is a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I wonder if there is a one-liner.

No oneliner that I know of: you still need to get the SHA1 for the latest release, before being able to provide the file URL.
The problem is: the end result (file URL) will be a static one, and if there is a new release, you will have to compute the URL again.

So you might construe something based on the [latest tag](https://gist.github.com/lukechilds/a83e1d7127b78fef38c2914c4ececc3c#gistcomment-2574561), like:

```
curl https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/blob/$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/$1/releases/latest" | jq -r .tag_name)/myfile.json
```