# GitHub Releases Download URL Redirect Doesn't Seem to Work

Tags: github, url

[I've checked out this here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987542/is-there-a-link-to-github-for-downloading-a-file-in-the-latest-release-of-a-repo), but following what's outlined there, I'm still getting "not found" on pages that I know have releases.

For example, if I want to download the latest URL for something like `https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/releases`, for a number of repositories dynamically, why do I get a 404 when I use `https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/releases/latest/download/package.zip`

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you assume that all releases are packaged into `package.zip`?

Comment: @NicoHaase, Hi, thanks—I may have misunderstood, but at the article I link in my post, there's some discussion about how it should redirect

Comment: Have you checked that further? I would assume that this is a problem with that specific package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to use GitHub's API for that, as [documented for releases](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases). The URL format is

> [https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Bowner%7D/%7Brepo%7D/releases)

For example, https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/symfony/releases lists all releases for a PHP package. The JSON node `zipball_url` contains a link to a ZIP package for each release.