# Download link for latest release of GitHub project

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, github, github-api

I am trying to add to my website a download link to the latest github release of a project. For example the link https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/archive/r3.0.0-rc7.zip does link to the latest release (as of today), but I do not want to hard-code the version number on the web site.

I found several questions about this issue, [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085978/github-url-for-latest-release-of-the-download-file) using curl, [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987542/is-there-a-link-to-github-for-downloading-a-file-in-the-latest-release-of-a-repo) or [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439239/github-latest-release).

I tried the solution using ajax which uses the github release API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML> <BODY>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        GetLatestReleaseInfo();   
    });   

    function GetLatestReleaseInfo() {
      $.getJSON("https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/releases").done(function (json) {
         var release = json[0];
         var asset = release.assets[0];
         var downloadURL = "https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/releases" + release.tag_name + "/" + asset.name;
         $(".mongodb-download").attr("href", downloadURL);   
      });    
    } 
</script>

<a href="GetLatestReleaseInfo();">Link</a> 
<a href="" onclick="location.href=this.href+downloadURL;return false;">Link2</a> 
<a href="" onclick="location.href=this.href+mongodb-download;return false;">Link3</a>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

but I do not manage to call the javascript function correctly, as it seems in my tries above (Link, Link2 and Link3). I'm not very familiar with javascript or ajax, so I'd appreciate any help; maybe there is a simpler way without Ajax?

Comment: looks like [`xss`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're loading an html page instead of their REST API.The correct url to get the tags is https://api.github.com/repos/mongodb/mongo/tags

> You may want to read more about github api over here - https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

Your html could look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML> <BODY>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function () {
     GetLatestReleaseInfo();  
});  


function GetLatestReleaseInfo() {
   $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/mongodb/mongo/tags").done(function (json) {
        var release = json[0];
        var downloadURL = release.zipball_url;
        $("#mongodb-download").attr("href", downloadURL);  
   });    
}  
</script>

<a id='mongodb-download' href="">Download latest mongo</a>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work; I use your function and link, then click on the link and get redirected to the same site. When I right-click and then "save link address", it saves me the address of my web site.

Comment: use `console.log()` in the function to detect the downloadURL also check console and make sure there arent any errors there.

Comment: not quite sure how... If I type `mongodb-download` into the console, it returns the tag with that ID. If I type `GetLatestReleaseInfo()` I get `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. In which part of my html file do I have to call `GetLatestReleaseInfo()`?

Comment: If your getting `$ is not defined` that means your not loading your jquery library or loading it after `GetLatestReleaseInfo()`

Comment: Now I am attempting to load jquery library with `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Typing `GetLatestReleaseInfo()` into the console gives me an uncaught error and a type error `undefined is not a function`

Comment: well I cant really tell what your doing but you probably declare `GetLatestReleaseInfo()` after calling it . anyhow I made a simple demo on paste bin to show you an example how it should look like - http://pastebin.com/bxhpw7W2

Comment: Works fine with the example you gave me, thanks! I edited the answer and added the full code.

Comment: One thing I noticed: When I put a second link to the same location, only the first one works. Example: putting `<a id='mongodb-download' href="">Download latest mongo 2</a>` just after the first link, won't do anything on click. Why is that?

Comment: You can only declare 1 id in an html document,id's are unique if you want to change multiple elements use class for that and then using `.each` function in jquery to manipulate all elements href attribute.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this worked well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready (function () {
                $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/mongodb/mongo/tags").done(function (data) {
                    $ ('#mongodb-download').attr ('href', data[0].zipball_url); 
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="mongodb-download">Download the latest version of MongoDB</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are getting problems with undefined, just change the `$` into `jQuery` and it should all work!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready (function () {
                jQuery.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/mongodb/mongo/tags").done(function (data) {
                    jQuery('#mongodb-download').attr ('href', data[0].zipball_url); 
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="mongodb-download">Download the latest version of MongoDB</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works for me, hope it helps!