# GIT - Download Latest tar.bz2

Tags: linux, git

I'm a newbie with GIT and I have what it likely a very silly question.

I want to download the most recent version of a project (Murmur) from GIT, but I don't want the source, I just want the pre-compiled tar.bz2 file.

When I go to https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/releases/latest it redirects me to the latest release version. I could do some magic with bash and manually find and download the file I'm looking for, in this case: https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/releases/download/1.2.15/murmur-static_x86-1.2.15.tar.bz2

However since this is on github I figure there must be a more efficient way to do this? All I've found so far is to clone the whole repo and compile from source, but that's not what i'm after...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple bash script that can do the work.

```
#!/bin/bash

url2download=`curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/mumble-voip/mumble/releases/latest" |grep tar.bz2 |grep browser_download_url |grep x86 |head -n 1 | awk -F":" '{print $3}' | awk -F"\"" '{print $1}' `
fullurl="https:$url2download"
curl -O $fullurl
```

You can also check [GitHub latest release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439239/github-latest-release)